# Nested create query using Prisma returns undefined

Tags: postgresql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am working on a workout app using Graphql Prisma and Postgres as my backend.
So far my prisma schema is as follows:

```js
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Exercise {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name      String
  numSets   Int
  holdTime  Int?
  owner     Workout? @relation(fields: [workoutId], references: [id])
  workoutId Int?
}

model Workout {
  id        Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime   @updatedAt
  category  String   
  exercises Exercise[]
}
```

The schema defines a Workout object that takes in a category and a list of Exercises. I am trying to create a workout with a list of objects using Prisma's nested create query however the list of exercises is not created. I can't tell if there is something wrong with my schema or my script.

The script that I am using to test out the create is:

```js
const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client")

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

async function main() {
    const newWorkout = await prisma.workout.create({
        data: {
            category: 'Push',
            exercises: {
              create: [
                {
                  name: "pushup",
                  numSets: 5
                },
                {
                  name: "headstand",
                  numSets: 3,
                  holdTime: 30
                }
              ]
            }
        }
    })
    console.log(newWorkout)

    const workout = await prisma.workout.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: 1
      }
    })
    console.log(workout.exercises)
}

main()
    .catch(e => {
        throw e
    })
    .finally(async () => {
        await prisma.$disconnect()
    })
```

Output from print statements:

console.log(newWorkout):
"{
id: 1,
createdAt: 2021-11-09T07:03:40.844Z,
updatedAt: 2021-11-09T07:03:40.848Z,
category: 'Push'
}"

console.log(workout.exercises):
"undefined"

Answer (score 2):

Prisma does not fetch `relation` fields by default. As a result, the  `exercises` field is not returned with the `workout` record. This applies to all queries, including the `create` and `find`.

To fetch the `exercises` field, you should use either [`include`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#include-all-fields-for-a-specific-relation) or [`select`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/select-fields). `include` is preferred if you want to return all the fields in the relation, whereas `select` lets you specify exact fields to return.

Here is the updated version of your code that returns the `excercises` field:

```js
const newWorkout = await prisma.workout.create({
        data: {
            category: 'Push',
            exercises: {
              create: [
                {
                  name: "pushup",
                  numSets: 5
                },
                {
                  name: "headstand",
                  numSets: 3,
                  holdTime: 30
                }
              ]
            }
        },
        include: {
            exercises: true
        }
    })

    console.log(newWorkout) 

    let workout = await prisma.workout.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: 1
      },
      include: {
          exercises: true
      }
    })
    console.log(workout.exercises)
```

Comment: Thank you using the include works and is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help :)

Comment: Have been looking into this for quiet some time, this answer helped thanks a lot!

Comment: Official docs - https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries